# Laravel : file validation issues

Tags: php, validation, file-upload, laravel-3

I'm having issues validating files with Laravel 3. Whatever I try, the validator passes. So uploading a mp4 when it should not be allowed works.. I know I'm not too far away, but I can't figure it out.

Here is the relevant part of my function my form is posting :

```
public function post_edit($id)
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $files = Input::file();

    $dev = new Dev();
    $upload = new Upload();

    $v_upload = Validator::make($files, $upload->rules);
    $v_dev = Validator::make($input, $dev->rules);
    if($v_dev->passes() && $v_upload->passes()) {
        //success

        $dev = Dev::find($id);
        //save input data to model then save...
        $dev->save();

        foreach($files as $key=>$file) {
            if($file['name'] != '') {
                $upload = new Upload;
                $upload->for = 'devs';
                $upload->for_id = $id;
                $upload->name = $file['name'];
                $upload->type = $file['type'];
                $upload->save();
                Input::upload($key, 'public/upload', 'd'.$id.'_'.$file['name']);
            }
        }

        $message = "Success!";

        return Redirect::to('/dev/'.$id)->with('message', $message);
    }
    else {
        //failure
        dd($v_upload);
    }
}
```

And my model :

```
class Upload extends Eloquent
{
    public static $table = 'uploads';
    public static $timestamps = false;

    public $rules = array(
        'size' => 'max:102400',
        'type' => 'mimes:png,jpg,gif,tiff,zip,tgz,css,html,js,php,txt,mp3,psd,csv,xls,xlsx,ppt,doc,docx'
    );
}
```

Also, my array of files (`Input::file()`) looks like this:

```
array(2) {
  ["upload1"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(17) "facebook-logo.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpEGqXWT"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(12939)
  }
  ["upload2"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(15) "mobile-icon.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpygDS1k"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(8570)
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the content of $dev->rules ? If it's an empty array, no rules = validation OK

Comment: $dev->rules are assigned and validate well (I tried posting with an empty title and it told me title was required)